# Hey can you help me out . my 'url.parse' is deprecated

Tags: node.js, url, urlparse

**line 5**
@deprecated — since v11.0.0 - Use the WHATWG URL API.

The signature '(urlStr: string): UrlWithStringQuery' of 'url.parse' is deprecated
url .The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

Comment: Can you add more context please? What package is the deprecation warning from? What packages do you use for your project? What version of node are you using?

Comment: VERSION:V14.16.0

Comment: package. json file.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution that worked for me.

```js
const {URL} = require('url');

const getProfile = (req,res) => {
   const fullurl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
   //E.g. http://127.0.0.1:3000/getProfile?pid=12345&section=NE
   
   const urlObj = new URL(fullurl);
   console.log(urlObj.searchParams.get('pid'));
   //prints 12345
   
   console.log(urlObj.searchParams.get('section'));
   //prints NE
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The new method is use WHATWG API in Node.Js 
You can use the code below to get something like pathname:

```js
const uri = 'https://yoururl.com/yourpathname'
const { URL } = require('url');
const yourUrl = new URL(uri);
const yourPathame = yourUrl.pathname.substr(1);

// yourUrl return 'https://yoururl.com/yourpathname'
// yourPathame return 'yourpathname'
```

The reference about WHATWG API is at [Node.js website](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/url.html#url_whatwg_api).

Answer (score 1):

Built-in url.parse was deprecated. The up to date api is URL. You can find more here: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html